# Does Avianca really require you to speak Spanish to sit in an exit row?

Tags: air-travel

My Spanish is weak, at best. But I like the legroom of an exit row.
Does Avianca really limit exit row seats to Spanish speakers?

Answer (score 19):

[Officially](https://ayuda.avianca.com/hc/en-us/articles/13091668801947-How-can-I-choose-my-seat-) you need to be able to speak "Spanish or English" to sit in the exit row in general, or Spanish to sit in the window seat of an Exit Row.

However despite this being their official policy, there are multiple reports of people being removed from exit row seat (including non-window seats) if they do not speak fluent Spanish. I can't comment on how frequently this occurs for non-Window seats.

If you only speak basic Spanish (and at least reasonably good English) I would suggest selecting either an aisle or middle seat in the Exit Row and, at least based on their policy, you will be fine.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145843/discussion-on-answer-by-doc-does-avianca-really-require-you-to-speak-spanish-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The Spanish version (https://ayuda.avianca.com/hc/es/articles/13091668801947--C%C3%B3mo-puedo-reservar-mi-asiento-) states that you need to be able to read, speak and understand **English AND Spanish** ("Hablar, leer y entender inglés y español."